# Accessing multiple kivy Classes from one single Class within Python side

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I have two Classes in python and 2 labels available within 2 different Classes in Kivy file which I would like to control from a single Python Class:

```
Class Python(BoyLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Python, self).__init__(*kwargs)
        self.label1 = self.ids["label1"]
        self.label2 = self.ids["label2"]

   def changeText(self):
       self.label1.text = "New Text 1"
       self.label2.text = "New Text 2"

Class NewClass(BoxLayout):
    pass
```

On kivy I have:

```
<Python>:
    BoxLayout: "vertical"
        Label:
            id:label1
            text: "Text 1"

<NewClass>:
    BoxLayout: "vertical"
        Label:
            id:label2
            text: "Text 2"
```

In this example the change would only work for the change of label1 but of course it will not work for label2 as I need to access the NewClass property which is the part I am not able to workout.

Also i would like to control all the kivy variables from the 1st Class ("Python" in this example) - hopefully this is possible

Any cool help in order to understand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok after a good night of sleep I could find the solution myself which very easy:

1. Give an ID to "NewClass" in "Python":

   ```
   <Python>:
       BoxLayout: "vertical"
           Label:
                id:label1
                text: "Text 1"
           NewClass:
                id: newclass

   <NewClass>:
       BoxLayout: "vertical"
           Label:
               id:label2
               text: "Text 2"
   ```

Then on the .py side you need to call refer to newclass:
`self.newclassid = self.ids["newclass"]`

Then link the label id:

```
self.newclasslabel = self.newclassid.ids["label2"]
```

And finally change the text:

```
self.newclasslabel.text = "New Label 2"
```

Comment: Yes, the issue was that `NewClass` widget was not a child of `Python` and thus absent from its `ids`.